# Running Angular/JavaScript with c# back-end

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, backend

I am building an application with an AngularJS front-end framework. I am wondering if there are ways to run an Angular application with a C# back-end.

I was using Node.JS as the back-end environment for development, but the client I'm working for says they use C# as their company's back-end. I'm pretty sure they don't do web development (they contracted out for this project) and them downloading a new runtime environment like ASP.NET isn't a possibility.

Comment: This too broad question, simply put you _can_ make a front-end angular app based on ASP.NET WebAPI, voting to close

Comment: The short answer - there are few ways. But I agree with @MedetTleukabiluly, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Your front-end (JS/Angular) is (should be) agnostic of the back-end. All it does is call an API and get served either JSON data, or static assets. So yes, you can do it in C#.

The "default" C# back-end is indeed ASP.Net (possibly with MVC framework). I don't understand why your customer expects C#, but not a framework so suitable for use with IIS (I'm assuming they're on Windows servers, right?). But at any rate, you can roll out your own solution using a framework like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). It runs with or without ASP.Net (see documentation). I'm sure there are others.

I've recently had a similar discussion with one of my clients, who was adamant we develop the solution such that it runs under IIS, and utilizes their Active Directory and various other Windows services. I ended up utilizing [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) and some specific NPM modules, and it works tremendously well. The client sees another IIS app in their Internet Management console, along with logs and reports; we have a full Node/React app running underneath, managed by IISNode.

Comment: you're right, it's on a windows server. i'll try your suggestion and let you know what the result is.